# Qt5, X11, libxcb. Sliders and other parts of widgets is too small

Tags: qt, widget, size, xorg

Some parts of widgets (e.g. button in a QDateEdit) are by far too small so they cannot be properly used with touch screens.

On my system, the sliders, e.g. for the widget's scroll areas, become bigger if I use setGlobalStrut() accordingly. But a slider has buttons with arrows which are very small on our system. The same is true for QDateWidget. The Buttons with the arrows are very, very small in our system and therefore cannot be well used with touchscreen.

We use Pvbrowser (pvbrowser.org) for visualisation of a gas measurement device on an embedded system with touchscreen. It is running an embedded linux yocto/poky "jethroo". By passing a parameter, the application calls QApplication::setGlobalStrut. The effect is, that some elements become bigger, but not sub elements within the widget.

Is there any way to change the appearance of Qt applications on systems like this: 
X11 was used instead of egl because the vnc functionality is needed. A display manager is not used and the windows manager is "matchbox". Qt is version 5.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I have found a solution. The screen size was not set in X11 and xrandr reported 0 dpi. 
If I set the dpi, e.g. by calling "xrandr --dpi 146" from mconsole, the size of arrow elements etc. within dateTime widgets, scroll bars or other are adjusted accordingly when the application is restarted.

Not only the widgets and its elements are changed but also the font size since it is given in points which depends on dpi.